# I am struggling with an Android layout with ConstraintLayout and Barrier

Tags: android, layout, android-constraintlayout, barrier

I am struggling with an Android layout with ConstraintLayout and Barrier

https://gist.github.com/dscoppelletti/62130db0ed773712bdfe0128b27e327b

The widgets should be rendered vertically except for some pairs the should be rendered horizontally.

It is all right from the top down to the widgets `txtAddress` and `cmdAddress`.
The next widget `lblEventCategories`, instead of following below, is rendered at the top and then follows the next widgets just like I want.

I think the problem concerns the `Barrier` widgets, but I can't solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the *TextView* "lblEventCategories" remove the following line:

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/txtEventCategories"
```

Constraining the top to the bottom of the guideline should suffice. This will move things on the right direction.

There may be other issues, but this is one. I recommend going back to the top of the layout and add items one-by-one and check it out in the designer as you go.

Comment: Great!, this is the trick and that is enough for my job. But I would like understand why only that two widgets can't be chained and I am worried about the reliability of the ConstraintLayout, so I have issued a bug to Google http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144987885